Set persistent env variables in Dockerfile dynamically at building time
Im using a gitlab pipeline in order to deploy containers to a server. I need those containers to have env variables that I get from hashicorp vault.
The problem is that the number and names of those secrets are unknown to the pipeline so i get all the secrets from vault api but i dont know how to set them as ENV in dockerfile.
I tried passing them in one arg with --build-arg and parse them inside, but nothing i do seems to be persistent.
Is there a way to use ENV directive in a dynamic way?
What i have so for is an ARG, lets say "SECRETS" with this format
SECRET1=VALUE,OTHER_SECRET=OTHER_VALUE
The goal is to achieve the behaviour of
ENV SECRET1=VALUE
ENV OTHER_SECRET=OTHER_VALUE 



Is there a way to use ENV directive in a dynamic way?

That is not something supported out of the box.
You need to generate Dockerfile with your chosen templating langauge and then build it. For example:
sed 's/,/\n/g' <<<"$SECRETS" | sed 's/^/ENV //' >> Dockerfile

Rather than doing that, consider:

creating an shell script that will export the variables and the shell script to container entrypoint
or such shell script could parse and then export the variables from SECRET
creating an env file and using it with docker run --env-file

